# Can a comparator function be made from two conditions connected by an 'and' in python (For sorting)?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, comparison

I have a list of type:

```
ans=[(a,[b,c]),(x,[y,z]),(p,[q,r])]
```

I need to sort the list by using the following condition :

```
if (ans[j][1][1]>ans[j+1][1][1]) or (ans[j][1][1]==ans[j+1][1][1] and ans[j][1][0]<ans[j+1][1][0]):
     # do something (like swap(ans[j],ans[j+1]))
```

I was able to implement using bubble `sort`, but I want a **faster sorting method**. 
Is there a way to sort my list using the `sort()` or `sorted()` (Using comparator or something similar) functions while pertaining to my condition ?

Comment: Please show a concrete example of your input instead of `[(a,[b,c]),(x,[y,z]),(p,[q,r])]`

Comment: eg:[("Team1",[20,1]), ("Team2",[40,5]) ,....]

Comment: Please put the whole list (expected input),  and the expected output in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a comparator function that retuns a tuple; tuples are compared from left to right until one of the elements is "larger" than the other. Your input/output example is quite lacking, but I believe this will result into what you want:

```
def my_compare(x):
    return x[1][1], x[1][0]

ans.sort(key=my_compare)
# ans = sorted(ans, key=my_compare)
```

Essentially this will first compare the `x[1][1]` value of both `ans[j]` and `ans[j+1]`, and if it's the same then it will compare the `x[1][0]` value. You can rearrange and add more comparators as you wish if this didn't match your ues case perfectly.

Comment: What if i want to do comparison based on x[1][0] and x[1][1] at the same time ? eg: (a>b or c>d)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, you *have to* prioritise by something. What if `x[1][0]` is larger in one of the elements, but `x[1][1]` is larger in the other?

Comment: Yeah, what should i do in that case ?

Comment: @AdityaSaini That's what I'm asking you, what do you want to do in that case? You're saying you want to sort by both elements *at the same time*, but that makes no sense, logically. You need to rethink what you actually want to sort by.

Comment: @AdityaSaini For example, say you have `("Team1",[20,1])` and `("Team2",[10,2])` and you want to sort these based on the `[20, 1]` and `[10, 2]`, using both elements at the same time. Which one should come first? `20` is bigger than `10`, but `1` is smaller than `2`.